# Surface Pro with a Cintiq pen

Tags: microsoft-surface

Is it possible to use a more sensitive pen like the 
[http://www.amazon.com/Wacom-Cintiq-Art-Pen-digitizer/dp/B00083Y86G/ref=pd_bxgy_pc_img_y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00083Y86G)
I know that wacom digitizers allow cross-pen usage, I just was wondering what other pens they have tried on the surface pro and if it was more sensitive, also if the eraser worked.

Comment: Check out [What types of styluses would work on a Microsoft Surface?](http://superuser.com/questions/503399/what-types-of-styluses-would-work-on-a-microsoft-surface)

Comment: I saw that, it was mostly a discussion on capacitive vs wacom