# use surface pro 3 ntrig pen on regular windows 8 touch screen pc

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I wonder if its even possible? As I do not really see what's the apparent difference (excuse my innocent thought) between surface screen and a regular touch screen PC's one.

If not, is there a trick / work around to make the surface pro 3 wacom pen to work with regular windows8 touch screen pc?

Thank You

Comment: I don't believe it would work.  If you have the capability to connect BT devices you can simply try.  [Here](http://us.wacom.com/en/feeldriver/) are the drivers for the Wacom device in question handy utility to check if it will work.

Comment: The surface pro 3 uses an N-trig pen, not a Wacom pen. http://www.zdnet.com/article/making-pen-cool-again-how-n-trig-won-over-microsoft-for-the-surface-pro-3/ The Wacom drivers will not be applicable.

Comment: As somebody pointed out the surface pro 3 doesn't use a Wacom pen, shocked I missed that, I have a surface pro 3.  My response is the same it's unlikely to work

Comment: Lots of good info here: http://superuser.com/questions/503399/what-types-of-styluses-would-work-on-a-microsoft-surface

Comment: @Aaron Skomra So... basically, I can install that drive on my normal touch screen win8 pc, then it will work ? O.O Or I am just getting a wrong excitement going on lol